# FTP the files in Netsuite file cabinet to any Server?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to FTP the Netsuite file cabinet (contract pdf files assoc with Customer) files to a server using C#. I couldn't found any API in C# to search the records in Netsuite. Is any other way to get the files from file cabinet through C#. Please help me to achieve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetSuite in itself does not support FTP Protocol.

However, you can consume wsdl in C# and use [SuiteTalk](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/platform/developer/suitetalk.shtml) saved search APIs to pull file from NetSuite.

You may otherwise, write a RESTlet in NetSuite to return the files using saved search and pull that file in C# using HTTPS request. Beware, that if file is non-text the content would be received in base64 format.